# bash script reading lines in every file copying specific values to newfile

Tags: bash

I want to write a script helping me to do my work.
Problem: I have many files in one dir containing data and I need from every file specific values copied in a newfile.
The datafiles can look likes this:

```
Name   abc   $desV0
Start   MJD56669   opCMS v2
End   MJD56670   opCMS v2
...
valueX   0.0456   RV_gB
...
valueY   12063.23434 RV_gA
...
```

What the script should do is copy valueX and the following value and also valueY and following value copied into an new file in one line. And the add in that line the name of the source datafile. Additionally the value of valueY should only contain everything before the dot.
The result should look like this:

```
valueX 0.0456 valueY 12063 name_of_sourcefile
```

I am so far:

```
for file in $(find -maxdepth 0 -type f -name *.wt); do
    for line in $(cat $file | grep -F vb); do
        cp $line >> file_done
    done
done
```

But that doesn't work at all. I also have no idea how to get the data in ONE line in the newfile.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simplify your script a lot using awk:

```
awk '/valueX/{x=$2}/valueY/{print "valueX",x,"valueY",$2,FILENAME}' *.wt > file_done
```

This goes through every file in the current directory. When "valueX" is matched, the value is saved to the variable `x`. When "valueY" is matched, the line is printed.

This assumes that the line containing "valueX" always comes before the one containing "valueY". If that isn't a valid assumption, the script can easily be changed.

To print only the integer part of "valueY", you can use `printf` instead of `print`:

```
awk '/valueX/{x=$2}/valueY/{printf "valueX %s valueY %d %s\n",x,$2,FILENAME}' *.wt > file_done
```

`%d` is the format specifier for an integer.

If your requirements are more complex and you need to use `find`, you should use `-exec` rather than looping through the results, to avoid problems with awkward file names:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -iname "5*.par" ! -iname "*_*" -exec \
awk '/valueX/{x=$2}/valueY/{printf "valueX %s valueY %d %s\n",x,$2,"{}"}' '{}' \; > file_done
```

Comment: Ah, great. I love these geeks all alround the world that can find solution in minutes where I would fail even after "insert_long_time_span" <br \> Last thing: valueY should not copied as full number but only the leading number. i.e. 10023.5879 should become only 10023. Is that possible?

Comment: @feeling I've edited my answer again to show a better method than using a `for` loop with `find`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below :

```
egrep "valueX|valueY" *.wt | awk -vRD="\n" -vORS=" " -F':| ' '{if (NR%2==0) {print $2, $3, $1} else {print $2, $3}}' > $file.new.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

don't fight. I'm really thankful for your help and exspecially the fast answers.
This is my final solution I think:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $(find * -maxdepth 1 -iname "5*.par" ! -iname "*_*"); do
awk '/TASC/{x=$2}/START/{printf "TASC %s MJD %d %s",x,$2, FILENAME}' $file > mjd_vs_tasc
done
```

Very thanks again to you guys.

Comment: I'm glad your problem is solved. If you used my answer (or a very slight modification to it), you should accept it, rather than posting your own answer. By the way, if you are going to use a loop, you should move the redirection `> mjd_vs_tasc` outside the `done` part of the loop, otherwise you will overwrite your file every iteration.